# d3.js trouble updating labels and rings

Tags: javascript, d3.js, label

I'm trying to build a ring chart, but still have issues with the placement and updating of the legend, rings and values. Why is old data remaining and not getting removed?
http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/123/

if there is more or less data - the labels don't get placed correctly

```
 //draw labels                      
            valueLabels = value_group.selectAll("text.value").data(reversedata)
            valueLabels.enter().append("svg:text")
            .attr("class", "value")
            .attr("transform", function(d) {
                var rings = counts;

                return "translate("+(that.radius+55)/rings+", 0)";
            })
             .attr("dx", function(d, i){
                return 19*i;            })
            .attr("dy", function(d, i){
                return -5;
            })
            .attr("text-anchor", function(d){
                return "start";
            }).text(function(d){
                return d.value;
            });

            valueLabels.transition().duration(300).attrTween("d", arcTween)
            valueLabels.exit().remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [<kbd>**Fiddle**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/124/).

I couldn't get it worked with your data coz I don't have time right now.

But i managed to get this for you from this [**`link`**](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1096355).

Here the `innerRadius` is calculated using the index defined in the data.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I see. What about the labels being positioned horizontally. What about it taking on new data? Why are the labels/rings on my example not replenishing properly?

Comment: I've updated my example with an additional data set - http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/126/

Comment: Fixed the value displacement issue - http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/127/ - but updating is still a problem - it does not destroy the old values/legend

Comment: I've only been able to fix the application - by using jquery removes. http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/128/